# stdin of unknown string length to store

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

I'm currently writing a program that asks the user to input basic user information about themselves and storing it temporarily into memory so I can then later transfer to a binary file.

Here is my excerpt of code that is malloc'ing the variables.

```
userInput = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
firstName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
lastName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
companyName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
phoneNum = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
email = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

The above variables are all of unknown size except phoneNum which can be 10 characters long.

Then I ask user for input:

```
printf("First Name: ");
fgets(firstName, sizeof(firstName), stdin);

printf("Last Name: ");
fgets(lastName, sizeof(lastName), stdin);

printf("Company Name: ");
fgets(companyName, sizeof(companyName), stdin);

do{
    printf("Phone Number: ");
    fgets(phoneNum, sizeof(phoneNum), stdin);
    flag = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(phoneNum); i++){
        if(isdigit(phoneNum[i]) == 0){
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
} while (flag == 1);

printf("Email: ");
fgets(email, sizeof(email), stdin);


printf("-------------\nFirst: %sLast: %sCompany: %sPhone: %sEmail: %s\n", firstName, lastName, companyName, phoneNum, email);
```

My output when compiling:

What compiler shows:

```
First Name: Test
Last Name: Last
Company Name: Yes
Phone Number: 123456789
Phone Number: Email: johndoe@email.com
-------------
First: Test
Last: Last
Company: Yes
Phone: 89
Email: johndoe
```

It likely has to do with memory but I'm not sure how to malloc for a variable of size I don't know. My error checking for the phone also doesn't behave the way it is supposed to. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `sizeof(firstName)` is not correct. It's a common error. That gives the size of a pointer (which is a fixed value) and not the size of what was allocated. As for variable sized input, the general options are: define a MAX_SIZE if the requirements allow, or read one character at a time, or read one block at a time with realloc as needed.

Comment: Another problem in your code is that you expect reading into a buffer of `sizeof(char)` size will magically resize the array as needed. No. That's wrong. You've to do all the allocation yourself allocating and reading chunks of data and resizing to the required size at the end. What you currently do is allocate `sizeof(char)` bytes which is equal to 1 byte and read into it.

Comment: regarding lines like: `phoneNum = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);`  1) do not cast the returned value.  The returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer. Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined by the standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect on the parameter to `malloc()`.  Suggest removing those instances of that expression.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the code might want to use: `getline()` or `readline()` to input the users' responses, as there will be nothing left in stdin to mess up the next user response.

Comment: regarding the question statement: `output when compiling`  The listed outputs are from a run of the code, NOT from compiling

Comment: when asking about a run time problem, post code that is short, cleanly compiles and still shows the problem.  Then post the actual input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: @kaylum thanks that makes sense, user input is always unknown so I'll likely implement this using the read one character at a time method.

Comment: @CoolGuy Thank you for the clarification, but how come the first, last and company name are being saved into memory but the rest isn't, despite this?

Comment: You're reading into memory that isn't yours. A phenomenon called Undefined Behavior strikes. When UB strikes, anything could be the output. Sometimes it may silently work. Sometimes, it may not.